# How to get list of environment variable present in a windows machine using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables

I am looking for a way to get the list of all the environment variable in an windows machine using c#.

can anyone please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thank you very much, just found a method named Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() that helped me.